# Cross compile rust-openssl for Raspberry Pi 2

Tags: openssl, raspberry-pi, rust, cross-compiling

I am on a Debian machine and I want to cross compile a project for my Raspberry Pi 2. I've managed to do it for a simple hello world using rustup, but couldn't figure out how to cross compile the rust-openssl crate.

I have compiled openssl with arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc and installed it in my `home/opensslArm` directory.

When I run

```
OPENSSL_LIB_DIR=/home/johann/opensslArm/lib OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR=/home/johann/opensslArm/include cargo build --target=armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf
```

I get this error:

```
failed to run custom build command for `openssl-sys-extras v0.7.11`
Process didn't exit successfully: `/home/johann/projects/test/target/debug/build/openssl-sys-extras-e1c84960cd35bc93/build-script-build` (exit code: 101)
--- stdout
TARGET = Some("armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf")
OPT_LEVEL = Some("0")
PROFILE = Some("debug")
TARGET = Some("armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf")
debug=true opt-level=0
HOST = Some("x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu")
TARGET = Some("armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf")
TARGET = Some("armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf")
HOST = Some("x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu")
CC_armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf = None
CC_armv7_unknown_linux_gnueabihf = None
TARGET_CC = None
CC = None
HOST = Some("x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu")
TARGET = Some("armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf")
HOST = Some("x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu")
CFLAGS_armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf = None
CFLAGS_armv7_unknown_linux_gnueabihf = None
TARGET_CFLAGS = None
CFLAGS = None
running: "arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc" "-O0" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-g" "-fPIC" "-march=armv7-a" "-o" "/home/johann/projects/test/target/armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/debug/build/openssl-sys-extras-e1c84960cd35bc93/out/src/openssl_shim.o" "-c" "src/openssl_shim.c"
ExitStatus(ExitStatus(256))


command did not execute successfully, got: exit code: 1



--- stderr
In file included from src/openssl_shim.c:1:0:
/usr/include/openssl/hmac.h:61:34: fatal error: openssl/opensslconf.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
thread '<main>' panicked at 'explicit panic', /home/johann/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-88ac128001ac3a9a/gcc-0.3.28/src/lib.rs:840
note: Run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` for a backtrace.
```

I get the same error if I export the variables in question.

I don't know exactly what I am supposed to do, I am not an expert in cross compiling. Has anyone managed to do this?

EDIT: I was using rust-openssl 0.7.11. Upgrading to 0.7.13 fixed this issue (I can now see cargo compiling rust-openssl dependencies without an error) but I have now another one:

```
error: linking with `arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc` failed: exit code: 1
...

note: /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/5/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/johann/opensslArm/lib/libssl.a(s23_meth.o): relocation R_ARM_THM_MOVW_ABS_NC against `a local symbol' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/home/johann/opensslArm/lib/libssl.a: error adding symbols: Bad value
```

How can I add `-fPIC` flag? Should I recompile opensslArm with specific flags?

Comment: Having that `/usr/include/openssl/hmac.h` in the output is really suspicious. That's going to be your normally installed version of OpenSSL, not the custom version. I wonder if the [`#include <foo>` instead of `#include "foo"`](https://github.com/sfackler/rust-openssl/blob/875f4ccb39e3863c6592b6275e067bd7692031d7/openssl-sys-extras/src/openssl_shim.c#L1-L4) is going to cause a problem...

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I tried cloning rust-openssl and manually compile openssl-sys-extra ... and it worked!! So I did a `cargo update`, rust-openssl upgraded from 0.7.11 to 0.7.13 and now I have a `linking with `arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc` failed` error

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You must pass `shared` option when configuring openssl compilation (this will make `-fPIC` parameter be passed to the compiler).

Here is a sequence of commands that I used to test cross compiling a Rust program that prints the openssl version:

```sh
cd /tmp

wget https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.1t.tar.gz
tar xzf openssl-1.0.1t.tar.gz
export MACHINE=armv7
export ARCH=arm
export CC=arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc
cd openssl-1.0.1t && ./config shared && make && cd -

export OPENSSL_LIB_DIR=/tmp/openssl-1.0.1t/
export OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR=/tmp/openssl-1.0.1t/include
cargo new xx --bin
cd xx
mkdir .cargo
cat > .cargo/config << EOF
[target.armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf]
linker = "arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc"
EOF

cat > src/main.rs << EOF
extern crate openssl;

fn main() {
    println!("{}", openssl::version::version())
}
EOF

cargo add openssl # requires cargo install cargo-add
cargo build --target armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf
```

**Testing the compiled program on  the host computer**

[Setting](https://github.com/sfackler/rust-openssl#manual-configuration) `OPENSSL_STATIC` makes `rust-openssl` be statically linked. If you use the static linked version of `rust-openssl`, install a libc for armhf (`crossbuild-essential-armhf` [on Debian](https://wiki.debian.org/CrossToolchains)) and `qemu-static`, you can the run the compiled program with the command:

```sh
qemu-arm-static target/armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/debug/xx
```

Answer (score 6):

This is an older question but it shows up highly on Google, so I wanted to call out that nowadays you don't need to manually compile OpenSSL (if you don't want to). The `openssl` crate provides a [`vendored` feature](https://docs.rs/openssl/#vendored) that causes OpenSSL to be compiled from source when you build your project.

You can propagate the feature into your own project to optionally depend on `vendored` by adding something like this to your `Cargo.toml`:

```
[features]
...

# If compiling on a system without OpenSSL installed, or cross-compiling for a different
# architecture, enable this feature to compile OpenSSL as part of the build.
# See https://docs.rs/openssl/#vendored for more.
static_ssl = ['openssl/vendored']

[dependencies]
...

[dependencies.openssl]
optional = true
version = ...
```

Enabling the `static_ssl` feature when building your project will then compile OpenSSL against the same target architecture as the rest of your build.

[This post](https://github.com/rust-embedded/cross/issues/229#issuecomment-597898074) goes into some more details about different ways of compiling with OpenSSL.